# Random DatePicker crash

Tags: ios, crash, uidatepicker

I have a date picker and randomly received a crash saying there was more the 100,000 rows for it. How is that possible? Does anyone know why this error would of occurred, and how to prevent it in the future?

```
- (void)showDatePicker
{   

    actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil 
                                              delegate:nil
                                     cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                     otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [actionSheet setActionSheetStyle:UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent];


    datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 40, 0, 0)];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    NSString *startTimeString = [MathFunctions minutesToTimeString:[appointment.start_time integerValue]];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMdd h:mm a"];
    [dateFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
    NSString *dateTimeString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", appointment.date, startTimeString];

    datePicker.date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateTimeString];
    [actionSheet addSubview:datePicker];

    UISegmentedControl *closeButton = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"Done"]];
    closeButton.momentary = YES; 
    closeButton.frame = CGRectMake(260, 7.0f, 50.0f, 30.0f);
    closeButton.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
    closeButton.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [closeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(changeDate:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [actionSheet addSubview:closeButton];

    [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
    [actionSheet setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 485)];
    actionSheet.frame = CGRectMake(actionSheet.frame.origin.x, actionSheet.frame.origin.y, actionSheet.frame.size.width, 320);
}
```

Crash Reason:

```
Reason: Failed to allocate data stores for 100000 rows in section 0. Consider using fewer rows
```

Crashlytics Log:

```
CoreFoundation  __exceptionPreprocess + 162
1    libobjc.A.dylib    objc_exception_throw + 32
2    CoreFoundation +[NSException raise:format:]
3    Foundation -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 90
4    UIKit  -[UISectionRowData refreshWithSection:tableView:tableViewRowData:] + 1780
5    UIKit  -[UITableViewRowData numberOfRows] + 108
6    UIKit  -[UITableView noteNumberOfRowsChanged] + 118
7    UIKit  -[UITableView reloadData] + 730
8    UIKit  -[UIPickerView layoutSubviews] + 3430
9    UIKit  -[UIDatePickerView layoutSubviews] + 62
10   UIKit  -[UIPickerView _selectRow:inComponent:animated:notify:] + 80
11   UIKit  -[UIDatePickerView _selectRow:inComponent:animated:notify:] + 50
12   UIKit  -[UIDatePickerView _loadDateAnimated:] + 836
13   UIKit  -[UIDatePickerView _updateBitsForDate:forced:andReload:animateIfNeeded:] + 696
14   UIKit  -[UIDatePickerView _setDate:animated:forced:] + 348
15   UIKit  -[UIDatePickerView setDate:animated:] + 30
16   UIKit  -[UIDatePicker setDate:] + 36
```

Comment: Total guess, but maybe some combination of inputs, and possibly user local calendar settings, conspired to give you a date far in the future or past or something. I've never seen that before though, sorry. Hope someone has a more concrete answer.

Comment: You're really misusing `UIActionSheet` here. Don't do that.